# Gradle local dependency not found in runtime

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried to include the Google java `mybusiness` library from [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples) to my gradle project.
I added the folder to the root of my project, and tried to include it in my `build.gradle.kts` like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(fileTree("mybusiness") { include("**/*.jar") })
    // implementation(fileTree("mybusiness") { include("*.jar") })
    // implementation(files("mybusiness/google-api-services-mybusiness-v4-revsnapshot-1.25.0.jar"))
    // runtimeOnly(fileTree("mybusiness") { include("*.jar") })
}
```

I also tested the commented commands without success.
When I run it, compilation works, but in runtime I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with the following stacktrace:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/mybusiness/v4/MyBusiness$Builder
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:94)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

I appreciate any help on what might cause this exception, and how to include the classpath in the runtime as well. Thank you!

Comment: How are you running it? If you are building an ear or war, it could be that are not correctly bundling the libraries in the final deployable artifact.

Comment: Im running it over [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/), using `$gradle quarkusDev`